# What does "frags" mean?

Tags: terminology

While playing *League of Legends*, I read the word "frags" in chat. It was during the heat of battle so I couldn't ask my teammates, and I couldn't find anything on the *League of Legends* wiki.

What does this term mean?

Comment: Related: "gibbing" and "instagib" are derived from turning your opponent into giblets .

Comment: @tomeoftom true, but I still can't help pronouncing gib with a hard G rather than the J sound in giblets. Saying 'jib' and 'instajib' just sounds wrong.

Comment: Totally agree. Kind of surprised people still use these terms; they're so bleedingly '90s.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The term "Frag" comes from the shortening of "Fragmentation grenade".

> Fragging is a macabre ritual of Vietnam in which American enlisted men attempt to murder their superiors. The word comes from the nickname for hand grenades, a weapon popular with enlisted men because the evidence is destroyed with the consummation of the crime.

The original meaning would be classified as friendly fire. But it has evolved to mean murder/kill.

> A frag is roughly equivalent to "kill", with the typical main difference that the player being "fragged" can instantly respawn (play again) in most games, i.e. the "kill" is only temporary. In games it is mainly used as a kill count and score system

Sources :

[etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=frag)

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frag_%28video_gaming%29)

Comment: This is the best answer, both are uses for frag. It depends on what your referring to.

Comment: Note that traditionally (e.g. in Quake) frags are scored as kills - suicides, not just kills. This penalizes suicide as a way to deny the opponent a kill.

Comment: Additionally, "frag" as an abbreviation for "fragment" was used since about the 18th century, though usually with a dot after the word (that is, "frag.").

Comment: @desaivv: It's not actually very esoteric, and it's still used in this meaning for games which have "fragments" of something as important items (example usage from Lineage II boards: " [WTB Purple R95 Crystal/Frags](http://boards.lineage2.com/showthread.php?p=3280397) ".

Answer (score 11):

Kills. Can either be a present tense verb as in "Bob frags two enemies" or a noun as in "Bob has 4 frags."

Comment: I would like to add that "fragging" usually refers to killing characters/entities which respawn to be fragged again (like in a multiplayer match)

Answer (score 4):

Two meanings; It could mean kills or it could be in reference to frag grenades.

Answer (score 2):

Frags in league of legends is simply kills or Fragmention grenades, to the phrase, cookable frags, or ''come on! throw a frag at that thing! it's gonna blow! let's go let's go get it out there!'' so it means kills or grenades.